# Wireshark, wrong TCP ACKed unseen segment message

Tags: wireshark

I'm currently getting wrong "TCP ACKed unseen segment" messages in Wireshark.
(see picture)
I'm using Wireshark 4.0.0
It doesn't happen with Wireshark 3.6.5

I think it's a Bug in Wireshark, has anyone an idea?

[pcap screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PFAyT.png)

Comment: This doesn't seem to pertain to programming. Either [edit] the question to show how it's about programming, or consider asking on [su] or [networkengineering.se] instead.

Answer (score 0):

Open an issue about it on [the Wireshark issues list](https://gitlab.com/wireshark/wireshark/-/issues/).